# JNI calling wrong method

Tags: windows, windows-7, java-native-interface, java

We have a java application that calls a native method from a dll. This works for us most of the time but very rarely on some pcs the JNI is calling wrong native method. As we have finally a machine that reproduces the issue regurally we would like to investigate what is the reason and hopefully fix it, but we are out of ideas how to investigate the issue.

The following is a java crash dump. It is visible there that we are trying to invoke method setVolumeNative; the method create is invoked however.

We would expect to see the following on stack:
Java_net_inspiredbroadcast_legion_jni_volume_MainVolume_setVolumeNative

But we see there this:
Java_net_inspiredbroadcast_legion_jni_process_ProcessImpl_create

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6294c518, pid=14900, tid=7008
#
# JRE version: 7.0
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [common-win32-native-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.dll+0xc518]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x11969c00):  JavaThread "Bootstrap" [_thread_in_native, id=7008, stack(0x12890000,0x128e0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0d3871c0, ECX=0x730a3130, EDX=0x128df744
ESP=0x128df730, EBP=0x128df754, ESI=0x0d3871c0, EDI=0x11969c00
EIP=0x6294c518, EFLAGS=0x00010247

Top of Stack: (sp=0x128df730)
0x128df730:   6299f488 00000001 00000000 128df744
0x128df740:   00000001 00000000 80070490 00000000
0x128df750:   00000000 128df788 6294bb31 11969d28
0x128df760:   128df7c4 00000000 00000006 00000008
0x128df770:   11969c00 0d3871c0 0d3871c0 128df7bc
0x128df780:   0245a4b7 00969c00 128df7bc 0245a5b7
0x128df790:   11969d28 128df7c4 00000000 128df79c
0x128df7a0:   0d3871c0 128df7cc 0d387920 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x6294c518)
0x6294c4f8:   ff d1 c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00
0x6294c508:   8d 55 f0 52 6a 00 6a 01 68 88 f4 99 62 8b 45 f8
0x6294c518:   8b 08 8b 55 f8 52 8b 41 0c ff d0 89 45 f4 83 7d
0x6294c528:   f4 00 74 16 68 70 f1 99 62 68 90 f1 99 62 8b 4d 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0d3871c0 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
ECX=0x730a3130 is an unknown value
EDX=0x128df744 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x11969c00
ESP=0x128df730 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x11969c00
EBP=0x128df754 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x11969c00
ESI=0x0d3871c0 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
EDI=0x11969c00 is a thread


Stack: [0x12890000,0x128e0000],  sp=0x128df730,  free space=317k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [common-win32-native-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.dll+0xc518]  Java_net_inspiredbroadcast_legion_jni_process_ProcessImpl_create+0xa410
C  [common-win32-native-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.dll+0xbb31]  Java_net_inspiredbroadcast_legion_jni_process_ProcessImpl_create+0x9a29
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.jni.volume.MainVolume.setVolumeNative(I)V+0
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.jni.volume.MainVolume.setVolume(I)V+49
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.peripheral.win32.MainSystemVolume.setVolume(I)V+100
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.peripheral.win32.MainSystemVolume.startUp()V+49
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.service.impl.ServiceLoaderImpl.<init>()V+210
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.service.impl.ServiceHandler.initialise()V+176
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.core.BootstrapDelegate.start()Ljava/lang/Integer;+318
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.core.Bootstrap.start([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;+14
j  org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run()V+75
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1233ba]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1c8f7e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1235a3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x123607]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcd1ef]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1430af]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1711e9]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x10fac]  freefls+0x130
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x110b1]  __fls_getvalue+0x58
C  [kernel32.dll+0x133aa]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x3bf32]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x3bf05]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.jni.volume.MainVolume.setVolumeNative(I)V+0
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.jni.volume.MainVolume.setVolume(I)V+49
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.peripheral.win32.MainSystemVolume.setVolume(I)V+100
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.peripheral.win32.MainSystemVolume.startUp()V+49
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.service.impl.ServiceLoaderImpl.<init>()V+210
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.service.impl.ServiceHandler.initialise()V+176
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.core.BootstrapDelegate.start()Ljava/lang/Integer;+318
j  net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.core.Bootstrap.start([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;+14
j  org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run()V+75
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x11e76c00 JavaThread "CashHandlingWorker" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5732, stack(0x18e60000,0x18eb0000)]
  0x11e76800 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15856, stack(0x13220000,0x13270000)]
  0x11e76000 JavaThread "NetConn Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15932, stack(0x18560000,0x185b0000)]
  0x11c02800 JavaThread "AudioPlayerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=15000, stack(0x18b90000,0x18be0000)]
  0x11c02000 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14308, stack(0x185d0000,0x18620000)]
  0x11c01c00 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=8760, stack(0x17860000,0x178b0000)]
  0x11c01400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12852, stack(0x13280000,0x132d0000)]
  0x11c01000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=7156, stack(0x12f70000,0x12fc0000)]
  0x11c00800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16016, stack(0x12840000,0x12890000)]
  0x11c00000 JavaThread "TelnetServer" [_thread_in_native, id=6376, stack(0x12ed0000,0x12f20000)]
  0x11bffc00 JavaThread "EventWorker" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14384, stack(0x12280000,0x122d0000)]
  0x11bff000 JavaThread "ScheduleHandler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15584, stack(0x13050000,0x130a0000)]
  0x11a21400 JavaThread "MarimbaDownloadStatusMessenger" [_thread_blocked, id=10380, stack(0x113e0000,0x11430000)]
  0x11a06c00 JavaThread "MetersWorkingThread" [_thread_blocked, id=7028, stack(0x10d00000,0x10d50000)]
  0x119e4800 JavaThread "SuspensionEvaluatorDaemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12132, stack(0x12690000,0x126e0000)]
  0x119e3000 JavaThread "Announcer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12116, stack(0x129f0000,0x12a40000)]
  0x119e2800 JavaThread "Asyncmessage sending thread" [_thread_blocked, id=16036, stack(0x125f0000,0x12640000)]
=>0x11969c00 JavaThread "Bootstrap" [_thread_in_native, id=7008, stack(0x12890000,0x128e0000)]
  0x009adc00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=14360, stack(0x00b20000,0x00b70000)]
  0x1192bc00 JavaThread "Wrapper-Connection" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15560, stack(0x12640000,0x12690000)]
  0x118f9c00 JavaThread "Wrapper-Startup-Runner" [_thread_blocked, id=9208, stack(0x12760000,0x127b0000)]
  0x11918c00 JavaThread "Wrapper-Control-Event-Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15772, stack(0x12700000,0x12750000)]
  0x118c9400 JavaThread "Cerberus 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10816, stack(0x12330000,0x12380000)]
  0x11325000 JavaThread "ProcessHandler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14040, stack(0x11430000,0x11480000)]
  0x10529800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11748, stack(0x10ad0000,0x10b20000)]
  0x10525000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11232, stack(0x10bc0000,0x10c10000)]
  0x10523c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16228, stack(0x106f0000,0x10740000)]
  0x10522c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10324, stack(0x10b20000,0x10b70000)]
  0x104ca000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11864, stack(0x109d0000,0x10a20000)]
  0x104c4000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15388, stack(0x10a30000,0x10a80000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00aff800 VMThread [stack: 0x10760000,0x107b0000] [id=15344]
  0x1053d400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x10f10000,0x10f60000] [id=10968]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 718K [0x04450000, 0x049a0000, 0x06ef0000)
  eden space 4416K,   9% used [0x04450000, 0x044bda98, 0x048a0000)
  from space 512K,  54% used [0x04920000, 0x04966020, 0x049a0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x048a0000, 0x048a0000, 0x04920000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 6794K [0x06ef0000, 0x079a0000, 0x0c450000)
   the space 10944K,  62% used [0x06ef0000, 0x07592988, 0x07592a00, 0x079a0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 15616K, used 15582K [0x0c450000, 0x0d390000, 0x10450000)
   the space 15616K,  99% used [0x0c450000, 0x0d387a40, 0x0d387c00, 0x0d390000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x02450000, 0x02638000, 0x04450000)
 total_blobs=1078 nmethods=832 adapters=182 free_code_cache=30832Kb largest_free_block=31570240

Dynamic libraries:
0x00bf0000 - 0x00c1c000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\java.exe
0x77900000 - 0x77a80000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x767e0000 - 0x768f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x76790000 - 0x767d7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x766f0000 - 0x76790000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75870000 - 0x7591c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x774e0000 - 0x774f9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x76600000 - 0x766f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75320000 - 0x75380000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75310000 - 0x7531c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76cc0000 - 0x76dc0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x772a0000 - 0x77330000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76cb0000 - 0x76cba000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x769d0000 - 0x76a6d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x71020000 - 0x711be000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x77460000 - 0x774b7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76570000 - 0x765d0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76fd0000 - 0x7709c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\Windows\system32\QIPCAP.DLL
0x76920000 - 0x769af000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x76b50000 - 0x76cac000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x622b0000 - 0x6236d000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x5a810000 - 0x5ab36000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x740a0000 - 0x740d2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x769b0000 - 0x769b5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x71620000 - 0x7162c000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\verify.dll
0x645e0000 - 0x64600000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\java.dll
0x64580000 - 0x64593000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\zip.dll
0x64320000 - 0x64334000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\net.dll
0x770a0000 - 0x770d5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x77330000 - 0x77336000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x744b0000 - 0x744ec000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x71ba0000 - 0x71ba6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x718f0000 - 0x718ff000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\nio.dll
0x74190000 - 0x741a6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74150000 - 0x7418b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x72160000 - 0x72177000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x73cc0000 - 0x73ccb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x742f0000 - 0x74300000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x742e0000 - 0x742f0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x742c0000 - 0x742d2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x74270000 - 0x742b4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x74260000 - 0x74268000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x74250000 - 0x7425d000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x645b0000 - 0x645d7000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x74560000 - 0x7457c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x74550000 - 0x74557000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x74210000 - 0x74248000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x74200000 - 0x74206000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x71610000 - 0x7161a000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\management.dll
0x10c10000 - 0x10c5e000     C:\ikernel\dist\lib\wrapper.dll
0x744a0000 - 0x744a5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x62940000 - 0x629bd000     C:\ikernel\dist\lib\common-win32-native-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.dll
0x73690000 - 0x73699000     C:\Windows\system32\HID.DLL
0x770e0000 - 0x7727d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x76fa0000 - 0x76fc7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x77280000 - 0x77292000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x75920000 - 0x7656b000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x64060000 - 0x64158000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTUI.dll
0x755a0000 - 0x756bd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x75730000 - 0x7573c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x768f0000 - 0x7691d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
0x741e0000 - 0x741f2000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x73910000 - 0x7391d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x751b0000 - 0x751d1000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x76b00000 - 0x76b45000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
0x731a0000 - 0x731b2000     C:\Windows\system32\SAMLIB.dll
0x72f50000 - 0x72f72000     C:\Windows\system32\logoncli.dll
0x74330000 - 0x74339000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x5e750000 - 0x5e891000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\awt.dll
0x721a0000 - 0x72220000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x73010000 - 0x73068000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
0x75240000 - 0x75249000     C:\Windows\system32\version.dll
0x73e30000 - 0x73e43000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x70600000 - 0x707c3000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x72f40000 - 0x72f46000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x69130000 - 0x69f98000     C:\Windows\system32\nvd3dum.dll
0x72a80000 - 0x72aa5000     C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
0x628d0000 - 0x6293d000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\freetype.dll
0x602c0000 - 0x60345000     C:\ikernel\dist\openjdk7\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x76a70000 - 0x76af3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x737a0000 - 0x737dc000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x70ed0000 - 0x71000000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x744f0000 - 0x7453c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x637b0000 - 0x637c2000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\TortoiseOverlays\TortoiseOverlays.dll
0x72ac0000 - 0x72ad4000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub32.dll
0x63740000 - 0x637b0000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN32.dll
0x76dd0000 - 0x76f94000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
0x756c0000 - 0x756c4000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
0x774d0000 - 0x774d4000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
0x77340000 - 0x77344000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
0x76dc0000 - 0x76dc3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
0x774c0000 - 0x774c3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\normaliz.DLL
0x75380000 - 0x75595000     C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
0x778d0000 - 0x778d5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
0x633d0000 - 0x63735000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsvn_tsvn32.dll
0x633a0000 - 0x633c7000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn32.dll
0x632c0000 - 0x63396000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR110.dll
0x63280000 - 0x632b8000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libaprutil_tsvn32.dll
0x63fe0000 - 0x63fed000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\intl3_tsvn32.dll
0x63260000 - 0x63273000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsasl32.dll
0x72190000 - 0x72198000     C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
0x631d0000 - 0x63255000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110.dll
0x63150000 - 0x63181000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x71410000 - 0x71505000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x71e00000 - 0x71e70000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x74310000 - 0x74329000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x741d0000 - 0x741db000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x72b60000 - 0x72b6a000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x73990000 - 0x73a14000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
0x6f950000 - 0x6fae8000     C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x726a0000 - 0x726ce000     C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll
0x741b0000 - 0x741c2000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x71980000 - 0x71988000     C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
0x73e70000 - 0x73e99000     C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x71920000 - 0x71934000     C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x73780000 - 0x73798000     C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll
0x73800000 - 0x73808000     C:\Windows\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x74300000 - 0x7430f000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x5dc80000 - 0x5deb8000     C:\Windows\system32\wpdshext.dll
0x72ba0000 - 0x72d30000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_72d18a4386696c80\gdiplus.dll
0x60750000 - 0x607d9000     C:\Windows\system32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x64370000 - 0x6439b000     C:\Windows\system32\PortableDeviceTypes.dll
0x62270000 - 0x622af000     C:\Windows\system32\audiodev.dll
0x5d5b0000 - 0x5d817000     C:\Windows\system32\WMVCore.DLL
0x642e0000 - 0x6431d000     C:\Windows\system32\WMASF.DLL
0x64340000 - 0x64362000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x73070000 - 0x730a9000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.config -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Duser.language=en -Xmx128m -Djava.library.path=../lib/patch;../lib/level3;../lib/level2;../lib/level1;../lib;. -Dwrapper.key=dxgPdptyCLpDE9FBk2w3wf_1tGFfWs7N -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=14920 -Dwrapper.version=3.5.15-st -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=180 -Dwrapper.jvmid=2 -Dwrapper.lang.domain=wrapper 
java_command: net.inspiredbroadcast.legion.ikernel.core.Bootstrap
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ikernel\dist\lib;C:\ikernel\dist\lib;C:\ikernel\dist\bin\\..\lib
USERNAME=robert.dziwinski
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 4166716k(1004748k free), swap 8331576k(2764928k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK Client VM (22.0-b10) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0-INGG-administrator_2012_03_05_18_26-b00), built on Mar  5 2012 18:48:09 by "Administrator" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Mar 17 14:39:08 2015
elapsed time: 3 seconds
```

How to investigate such issues?

Comment: Investigation is already good! Now you need to dive into your .dll `Java_net_inspiredbroadcast_legion_jni_process_ProcessImpl_create`, and find out why it is crashing .... on win64bit only!??  (how are your experiences on other OS/architectures (32/64 bit))